# Definition of singular cubical homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

As we know , a continuous function $T : [0,1]^{n} \to X$ is called a singular $n$ cube in $X$ . Denote $Q_{n}$ is free abelian group with basis is the set of all singular $n$ cube in $X$ . Let $D_{n},C_{n}$ are free abelian group generated by degenerate cubes and nondegenerate cubes , respectively . Is $Q_{n}$ the direct sum of $D_{n}$ and $C_{n}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies: I originally misunderstood your question.

In singular *cubical* homology, degenerate cubes are cubes that are constant in one of the coordinates.

The group $C_n$ is defined to be the *quotient*,
$$ C_n = \frac{Q_n}{D_n}.$$
This is the appropriate relationship between $Q_n$, $D_n$ and $C_n$.

From the way your question was asked, I would assume that you were thinking of the elements in $C_n$ as cube chains. They are not. The elements in $C_n$ are *equivalence classes* of cube chains, modulo some degenerate cubes that you ignore.

Note that the boundary map $\delta_n$ sends $D_n$ into $D_{n-1}$, which ensures that $\delta_n$ descends to a well-defined map from the quotient $C_n$ to the quotient $C_{n - 1}$.

Comment: The degenerate cubers are very important: If one naively define the singular cubical homology naively one does not obtain the ordinary singular homology. One has to quotient out the degenerate cubes first. You can see this explicitly when one computes the homology of a point.